# Two way binding with ObservableCollection<string> in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am using a bindable `StackLayout` to show a series of `Entry` bound to an `ObservableCollection<string>` (`Addresses` in the the viewModel down).

It is not a problem to show on the UI the content of the collection, but if I modify the content of any of the `Entry`, it does not get reflected back in the original `ObservableCollection`

Here is the view model:

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Addresses { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            AddCommand = new Command(AddEmail);
            Addresses = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Addresses.Add("test1");
            Addresses.Add("test2");
        }

        void Add()
        {
            AddCommand(string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

And here is the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestList.MainPage"
             x:Name="page">
    <StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Addresses"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
                    Text="+" FontSize="Title"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Entry Text="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Text="-" FontSize="Title""/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I suspect that this is due to the fact that I am working on strings, and as such they cannot be modified in place. Do you have a suggestion on how to solve this problem without introducing a wrapper class or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the value of source in code behind by editing the text in Entry .You need to implement the interface **INotifyPropertyChanged** in  class  of ObservableCollection .

Define a model class

```
public  class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        string content;

        public string Content
        {

            get
            {
                return content;
            }

            set
            {
                if (content != value)
                {
                    content = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Content");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Addresses { get; set; }
```

```
Addresses = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
Addresses.Add(new MyModel() {Content = "test1" });
Addresses.Add(new MyModel() { Content = "test2" });
```

#### in xaml

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is also what I thought. But you can see that this is creating a wrapper class around a string in order to have the two way binding, and it's definitely a class that would be used only for this very specific case. That's why I would have loved to have another way of achieving the same result without creating another class.

Comment: I think this is  the only way or the easiest way  in runtime .

Answer (score 2):

You really need a wrapper class for this to work, besides if the syntax is too lengthy you can install `PropertyCHanged.Fody` package
Then all you need to do is add this tag:

```
  [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

And in the wrapper class:

```
  [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually what bothers me in this case it's not the need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but the fact that I need to create a wrapper class :)

Comment: I used to get annoyed by that too, but just do it and be done :).